# Can I measure with Keras how much memory a network needs during training / inference?

Tags: keras

I would like to know for a given training setup (model, optimizer, batch size) how much memory my network needs. Can Keras automatically give me this number?

Also interesting: How much memory is needed during inference?

Comment: Similar to [What is the memory cost of a CNN?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16292/8820)

Comment: it is not an easy task for the exact value, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/estimating-gpu-memory-consumption-of-deep-learning-models-2/